# Get a javascript error and solve

Tags: javascript, function, typeerror

I need to use jivosite chat plug-in to a particular style that I had to change fonts.

I found a javascript code which now faces a series of errors, but this code is executed correctly

```
<script type='text/javascript'>function jivo_onLoadCallback() {
    $('#jivo_container').contents().find("head")
        .append($("<style type='text/css'> *, body, div{font-family:iransans!important;} #jivo-chat #input-field {direction: rtl;} #jivo-chat #messages-div .new-msg-container.agentMessage {text-align: right;direction: rtl;}#jivo-chat #messages-div .new-msg-container.clientMessage {direction: rtl;} #jivosite-iframe-chat #jivo-chat #messages-div .new-msg-container.agentMessage{direction:rtl;text-align:right;}#agent-typing{direction:rtl;}.new-msg-text-inner{line-height:25px!important;text-align:justify !important;}.jivo-bottom-left-square{background-color:#216bf3 !important}#header-avatar.no-avatar .info .agent-name{font-family: iransans !important;}#jivo-label-inner-text{font-family: iransans !important;}#offline-form .description{line-height: 30px;text-align: right;font-size: 14px;}#offline-form .message textarea{height:50px;}#offline-form .input-field{text-align: right;}#offline-form .buttons.single div .jivoBtn{width: 100%;margin-top: 3px;background-color: #03a9f4;}</style>"));
}</script>
```

3 identical error on devtools chrome console is displayed.

```
Uncaught TypeError: q.test is not a function
at Function.fa [as find] (jquery.min.js?ver=4.7.3:2)
at n.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js?ver=4.7.3:2)
at n.fn.init (jquery.min.js?ver=4.7.3:2)
at n (jquery.min.js?ver=4.7.3:2)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):1511)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.min.js?ver=4.7.3:3)
at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery.min.js?ver=4.7.3:3)
at jquery.min.js?ver=4.7.3:2
at ia (jquery.min.js?ver=4.7.3:2)
at fa.setDocument (jquery.min.js?ver=4.7.3:2)
```

Sorry if you type my English is poor. I am Iranian and I translated with Google translate is.

Here's how the top tips favor if I fix the error. Thank

Comment: Does the error actually disappear if you delete or comment out that piece of code?

Comment: could be a dependency problem ... might be hard to explain since you communicate thru google translate though

Comment: Yes. When I removed the error code is not displayed.

Web: www.alirezaix.ir

I understand that guidance with regards to having learned the English language and explanation, is difficult. I will be grateful if you go to the above website address and see the problem firsthand.

Thanks for your kindness